# Get a maximum value from a list with Python

Tags: python, max

I have a datafile, from which I only require the maximum value contained within the 3rd column. I wrote the following code:

```
def testing():
file_reading = open("source_file.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") 
file_steps_yearly_sum = 0
file_steps_daily_list = []
while (True):
    row = file_reading.readline() 
    if len(row) == 0: 
        break
    else:
        steps = row.split(';')[2]
        file_steps_yearly_sum = int(file_steps_yearly_sum) + int(steps)
        #file_steps_list.append(row.split(';')[2])
        file_steps_daily_list.append(steps)
print(max(file_steps_daily_list))
print(file_steps_yearly_sum)
file_reading.close()
return file_steps_daily_list, file_steps_yearly_sum
```

The calculated sum is correct (checked it with excel), but the max method gives me 9928, which is clearly wrong. Just looking at the input file I can see values well over 10 000 present. I don't get it, should be a one-liner.

Just to be sure, did the same with a loop:

```
def max_num_in_list(file_steps_daily_list):
max = file_steps_daily_list[ 0 ]
for steps in file_steps_daily_list:
    if steps > max:
        max = steps
return max
```

Again, 9928. The list I extracted from the 3rd column of the source file was:

['3766', '12049', '14624', '12244', '12353', '12883', '11079', '10382', '11491', '14863', '8607', '15768', '9308', '10369', '11240', '12316', '14224', '10806', '9511', '7680', '12966', '11112', '14996', '15939', '11097', '5904', '15145', '9319', '15927', '11093', '8978', '9777', '10945', '9928', '12438', '10862', '12461', '11435', '15788', '10483', '5110', '15148', '12534', '12806', '14360', '10890', '11102', '6314', '10931', '12354', '6986', '14972', '13312', '10307', '9032', '10941', '8279', '10040', '14651', '8613', '7798', '13348', '10173', '15510', '15158', '13350', '10725', '8819', '17705', '12188', '10588', '9329', '9855', '8263', '8568', '7943', '20916', '15909', '23344', '14633', '31589', '17501', '15623', '27245', '14883', '13990', '11854', '12016', '4131', '5286', '6542', '6165', '9261', '11257', '11418', '5848', '6240', '4718', '10072', '7737', '6313', '13311', '14479', '6472', '6411', '7662', '8918', '13317', '17446', '5920', '7435', '9381', '12857', '7828', '8645', '12074', '12183', '8771', '4522', '5575', '8379', '8759', '8803', '7046', '12604', '10126', '11097', '8137', '6297', '10037', '5261', '5498', '10552', '4577', '8059', '5404', '4995', '8932', '6457', '10056', '9578', '11464', '11847', '5212', '13996', '11114', '8130', '10293', '9456', '12363', '8990', '11352', '5656', '15293', '5777', '8666', '8810', '8257', '6530', '10545', '8240', '10257', '8968', '10885', '14032', '14824', '14065', '9459', '11654', '13685', '20181', '11789', '15220', '17844', '17542', '9152', '11382', '9120', '10311', '14250', '19197', '22475', '12806', '13575', '7773', '4581', '14411', '10262', '25511', '17731', '10729', '16751', '13167', '14036', '12650', '11697', '12388', '14691', '18434', '5770', '9392', '9802', '10770', '10666', '10270', '12637', '16612', '10226', '9296', '6447', '10558', '8255', '11657', '10749', '10691', '10692', '10202', '10129', '6985', '8428', '13951', '10186', '7663', '10325', '8022', '6410', '13082', '8145', '8342', '6718', '7665', '4771', '10337', '11529', '10757', '10578', '8330', '10803', '10465', '4351', '10575', '18682', '10668', '7541', '10318', '11217', '6072', '14779', '14593', '10970', '9538', '11130', '16437', '4732', '10523', '9428', '4023', '8045', '9397', '12765', '8888', '11324', '10952', '8924', '10643', '11467', '15881', '11923', '13584', '13399', '11940', '10092', '7739', '9582', '11673', '8454', '11401', '10040', '11706', '10589', '7475', '9097', '14294', '14672', '10227', '7452', '11680', '14223', '15035', '11698', '15239', '8878', '9530', '11068', '6766', '10737', '10805', '13559', '9126', '10331', '8525', '4224', '5898', '7549', '14848', '11776', '13216', '8420', '6104', '6193', '7448', '8403', '7286', '11457', '11537', '4463', '6693', '3723', '12183', '10768', '18342', '13224', '10874', '7713', '12385', '14665', '10184', '10272', '11718', '12757', '11296', '18269', '11295', '10987', '11690', '5036', '7402', '8013', '12001', '8734', '12941', '10298', '11536', '10947', '14931', '18185', '9139']

Obviously, 9928 is not the maximum value. What is going on? Why max() won't give me the maximum value?

Comment: Note that `file_steps_daily_list` is a list of strings, not a list of `int`s.

Comment: change the last line in the else block to `file_steps_daily_list.append(int(steps))`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, Oww. Yes, I see now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```py
a = ['3766', '12049', '14624', '12244', '12353', '12883', '11079', '10382', '11491', '14863', '8607', '15768', '9308', '10369', '11240', '12316', '14224', '10806', '9511', '7680', '12966', '11112', '14996', '15939', '11097', '5904', '15145', '9319', '15927', '11093', '8978', '9777', '10945', '9928', '12438', '10862', '12461', '11435', '15788', '10483', '5110', '15148', '12534', '12806', '14360', '10890', '11102', '6314', '10931', '12354', '6986', '14972', '13312', '10307', '9032', '10941', '8279', '10040', '14651', '8613', '7798', '13348', '10173', '15510', '15158', '13350', '10725', '8819', '17705', '12188', '10588', '9329', '9855', '8263', '8568', '7943', '20916', '15909', '23344', '14633', '31589', '17501', '15623', '27245', '14883', '13990', '11854', '12016', '4131', '5286', '6542', '6165', '9261', '11257', '11418', '5848', '6240', '4718', '10072', '7737', '6313', '13311', '14479', '6472', '6411', '7662', '8918', '13317', '17446', '5920', '7435', '9381', '12857', '7828', '8645', '12074', '12183', '8771', '4522', '5575', '8379', '8759', '8803', '7046', '12604', '10126', '11097', '8137', '6297', '10037', '5261', '5498', '10552', '4577', '8059', '5404', '4995', '8932', '6457', '10056', '9578', '11464', '11847', '5212', '13996', '11114', '8130', '10293', '9456', '12363', '8990', '11352', '5656', '15293', '5777', '8666', '8810', '8257', '6530', '10545', '8240', '10257', '8968', '10885', '14032', '14824', '14065', '9459', '11654', '13685', '20181', '11789', '15220', '17844', '17542', '9152', '11382', '9120', '10311', '14250', '19197', '22475', '12806', '13575', '7773', '4581', '14411', '10262', '25511', '17731', '10729', '16751', '13167', '14036', '12650', '11697', '12388', '14691', '18434', '5770', '9392', '9802', '10770', '10666', '10270', '12637', '16612', '10226', '9296', '6447', '10558', '8255', '11657', '10749', '10691', '10692', '10202', '10129', '6985', '8428', '13951', '10186', '7663', '10325', '8022', '6410', '13082', '8145', '8342', '6718', '7665', '4771', '10337', '11529', '10757', '10578', '8330', '10803', '10465', '4351', '10575', '18682', '10668', '7541', '10318', '11217', '6072', '14779', '14593', '10970', '9538', '11130', '16437', '4732', '10523', '9428', '4023', '8045', '9397', '12765', '8888', '11324', '10952', '8924', '10643', '11467', '15881', '11923', '13584', '13399', '11940', '10092', '7739', '9582', '11673', '8454', '11401', '10040', '11706', '10589', '7475', '9097', '14294', '14672', '10227', '7452', '11680', '14223', '15035', '11698', '15239', '8878', '9530', '11068', '6766', '10737', '10805', '13559', '9126', '10331', '8525', '4224', '5898', '7549', '14848', '11776', '13216', '8420', '6104', '6193', '7448', '8403', '7286', '11457', '11537', '4463', '6693', '3723', '12183', '10768', '18342', '13224', '10874', '7713', '12385', '14665', '10184', '10272', '11718', '12757', '11296', '18269', '11295', '10987', '11690', '5036', '7402', '8013', '12001', '8734', '12941', '10298', '11536', '10947', '14931', '18185', '9139']

int_list = list(map(int,a))

print(max(int_list)) #31589
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a list of strings, and the max function compares the char value of each character, not the integer value of the number.

Cast list elements to int first, like you did for the sum.

```
print(max([int(i) for i in file_steps_daily_list]))
```

Answer (score 1):

First make sure `steps` is an **int** then use it across board

```
...
else:
    steps = int(row.split(';')[2])
    file_steps_yearly_sum = int(file_steps_yearly_sum) + steps
    #file_steps_list.append(row.split(';')[2])
    file_steps_daily_list.append(steps)
```

and then you can print

```
print(max(file_steps_daily_list))
```